# Kotlin - Difference between var vs object declaration

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between

```
object Foo : Any() { ... }
```

and

```
val Foo = object : Any() { ... }
```

Are there any semantic and/or logical differences, and when should they be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `object Foo : Any() { ... }`

  This is an [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations), which declares a singleton-like type `Foo` whose single instance contains the members declared inside the `object` scope and is lazily initialized upon first access. It may be used on top level or inside another type, but not inside function bodies. When declared inside another type, it will still only create a single object, not an object per instance of the enclosing type.

  ```
  class Bar {
      object Foo : Any() { ... } // only one object is created
  }
  ```

  Object declarations are typically used to encapsulate global singleton state and group the related public API members. However, as `Foo` can be used as an ordinary object, there are more use cases. One of them is having an `object` declaration as a subtype of a [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes).
- `val Foo = object : Any() { ... }`

  This is an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions), and it may be used inside function bodies as well. When it's evaluated, it creates a new object each time. In particular, if it's declared inside another type, it will create a new object for each instance of the enclosing type.

  ```
  class Bar {
      val foo = object : Any() { ... } // new object for each instance of Bar
  }
  ```

  When declared at the top level, it will still be a singleton, but it will initialize upon first access to the file facade class (which contains the other top level members of that file) and not to the `val`.

  When you declare a property this way, you won't be able to call the members that you add inside the `object` scope on the property, as opposed to the object declaration. However, when used as a local variable, such a `val` will expose its additional members.

  ```
  // on top level:
  val foo = object : Any() { 
      val x = 1
  } 

  fun main() {
      println(foo.x) // error, unresolved reference 'x'

      val bar = object : Any() { 
          val x = 1
      }
      println(bar.x) // OK
  }
  ```

  <sup>The purpose of this limitation for properties is to avoid having public API in anonymous classes (that object expressions are compiled to) which may implicitly change in an incompatible way upon next compilation. Object declarations, on contrary, declare a named type.</sup>

  Both object expressions and object declarations can inherit from a class and implement interfaces. Object expressions are particularly useful when you need to provide an instance of an interface that you don't want to implement with a class (e.g. it's an ad-hoc implementation that won't be used anywhere else):

  ```
  // in a library:
  interface ResponseHandler {
      fun onSuccess(response: Response): Unit
      fun onError(exception: Exception): Unit
  }

  fun Request.execute(responseHandler: ResponseHandler) { ... }
  ```

  ```
  // your code:
  val request: Request = ...

  request.execute(object : ResponseHandler {
      fun onSuccess(response: Response) { ... } // provide the implementations
      fun onError(exception: Exception) { ... } // for these two functions
  })
  ```

<sup>Note: in both cases, you can omit `: Any()`, as `Any` is the default supertype for both object declarations and object expressions.</sup>